# Programmatically Create Columns in DataGridiew in-between other columns

Tags: c#, datagridview, multiple-columns

I found the code below to just add columns programmatically.

```
private void AddColumnsProgrammatically()
{
    // I created these columns at function scope but if you want to access 
    // easily from other parts of your class, just move them to class scope.
    // E.g. Declare them outside of the function...
    var col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    var col4 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

    col3.HeaderText = "Column3";
    col3.Name = "Column3";

    col4.HeaderText = "Column4";
    col4.Name = "Column4";

    dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] {col3,col4});
}
```

Now I have no problem creating the columns but what I am after is adding these new columns inbetween lets say Column 1 and Column 2,   so Column 2 would shift over to now be Column 4 and the 2 new columns would be Column 2 and Column 3.

Is there any advice anybody can give me or a direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [DataGridView.Columns.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.insert(v=vs.110).aspx) method to insert a column at a specific index:

```
private void AddColumnsProgrammatically()
{
    // I created these columns at function scope but if you want to access 
    // easily from other parts of your class, just move them to class scope.
    // E.g. Declare them outside of the function...
    var col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    var col4 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

    col3.HeaderText = "Column3";
    col3.Name = "Column3";

    col4.HeaderText = "Column4";
    col4.Name = "Column4";

    // dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] {col3,col4});
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, col3);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, col4);
```

}